# How to open Jupyter lab when double clicking on .ipynb file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

To enable double click on `ipynb` file and to open in a browser.

First, I installed `nbopen` package

```
python -m pip install nbopen
```

After that, integrated into file manager so double click can be enabled, using the following command

```
python -m nbopen.install_win
```

All good, except the ipynb file is getting opened in *Jupyter Notebook* instead of *Jupyter Lab*.

When i try to open through cmd line, *Jupyter Lab* is getting opened as expected. How to open *Jupyter Lab* even when i double click the file ?